# Xamarin.Forms.ContenPresenter does not show content on UWP App with Native Toolchain enabled

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp, contentpresenter

I've the problem that our Xamarin.Forms app is not showing any content on UWP that's represented by a ContentPresenter when the app is compiled with .NET Native toolchain is enabled (Release).

It's not giving an error message or exception at all. I thought there might be a renderer assembly that has to be imported when using .net native. But for ContentPresenter there seems to be no available.

Using the latest stable Xamarin.Forms V2.5.0.280555
on Visual Studio 2017 15.5.7
targeting Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (1709)

That's one example on how i use it, but there are multiple occurences in our app, that keeps hiding content only when compiled native.

```
<Style TargetType="control:NavigationDrawer">
    <Setter Property="ControlTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <control:PageHeader Grid.Row="0" BindingContext="{TemplateBinding BindingContext}"/>

                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Content="{TemplateBinding PageContent}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

                    <control:DrawerGripArea Grid.Row="2" BindingContext="{TemplateBinding BindingContext}"
                                            OpenDrawerCommand="{Binding Source={x:Reference navBar}, Path=ToggleMenu}"/>
                    <control:NavigationBarControl x:Name="navBar" Grid.Row="3" BindingContext="{TemplateBinding BindingContext}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Please post some code so that we are able to see how the ContentPresenter is used in your code

Comment: Sorry, i added some usage code. :)